# building a route for another domain

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a site on the local server and on the production server. on the local site it has the dom1 domain, on the production domain1.com .
Now, I want to add to the site another domain for another controller:

```
smth_dom2:
    resource: "@SmthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: "{domain}"
    requirements:
        domain: dom2|domain2.com
```

There are dom2 is the domain on the local server, and domain2.com is on production. All correct.
But now I can’t build a route without a domain definition.

```html
{{path ('smth_dom2')}}
```

in the template requires a domain. If I modify the route with the default parameter, I must define domain:

```
smth_dom2:
    resource: "@SmthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: "{domain}"
    defaults: {domain: "dom2"}
    requirements:
        domain: dom2|domain2.com
```

How can I make the route on the local server be built with dom2, and on production domain2.com?

Comment: All generated routes should match the current host, since it determines it from the `RequestContext`. The [`requirements`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing) option will limit the domain this route will be accesible from. Do you want to generate cross-domain urls? This might be overcomplicating things unless is your intended usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to set the domain to `dom2` on your route and then override the domain from the `config/routes_prod.yaml`.

Ex:

routes.yaml

```yaml
smth_dom2:
    resource: "@SmthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: dom2
```

routes_prod.yaml

```yaml
smth_dom2:
    resource: "@SmthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: domain2.com
```

Note that the children routing files MUST NOT define any host parameter or the default define in the parent will be discarded.

Comment: Many thanks!
I was able to split the routes by servers